# Init state issue with "@@redux/init" in Redux

Tags: initialization, redux, state

I have a reducer as the following

```
const TopLinkReducer = (state = {'currentLink':'Main'}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'switchTopLink':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
          currentLink: action.id
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default TopLinkReducer
```

and my goal is the provide a initial state as {'currentLink':'Main'} but I expect the {'currentLink':'Main'} should be passed in initially but I got "@@redux/init" and something else...

What did I missing?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is the default behavior of redux (see https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/src/createStore.js#L242). When the store is created, an init-action (type `@@redux/init`) is dispatched to retrieve the initial state.

Your reducer should handle the unknown `@@redux/init` action by just returning the unchanged state.

The code in your example looks correct, I entered it into this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v1kvcjbu/46/ and it works as intended (`currentLink` is `'Main'` after the call to `createStore`).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, It was in the difference between the **store initial State**.

```js
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import reducers from './reducers';
import storeInitialState from './initialState';

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    storeInitialState,
  //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);
```

Vs the **reducer initial state**.

```js
import {
    handleReturningUserReducerInitialState,
} from '../initialState';

export const userReducer = (
    state = handleReturningUserReducerInitialState(),
          //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
         // It returns the same result as storeInitialState except It was checking for the values in the localStorage
    action
) => {
...
}
```

They were overwriting each other.